# Can't "connect" to new repos via ssh on a git server

Tags: git, ssh, server, connection

I have some repos on a local server which I access over ssh and with git.
I have one repo created whic I can operate, the problem appears when I try to create a new repo and operate.

I push something on an already created repo:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcDjc.png)

And when I create a new repo on the same folder on the server. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfsHG.png)

Ok now all went well, the problem comes now, when I try to push some file there: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMGF3.png)

It stucks there and no longer finishes.

I've already tried to regen ssh rsa keys but I doubt it's the problem due to I can push from another repo...

Comment: Ok I made a mistake I was creating the repo in the root user not the git user. Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was creating the repo in the root user not the git user.

Yes, your first screenshot shows a working push, meaning Git looks and find the private/public keys in `/home/git/.ssh`

You would need a `/root/.ssh/config` file in order to specify in it the path of the private key to use, if you wanted for root to reuse the same credentials.